# CocoaPods: App.xcworkspace does not exists

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

This is what happened:

```
$ pod lib lint

 -> MXKit (5.2.2)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  xcodebuild: error: 'App.xcworkspace' does not exist.

[!] MXKit did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.
```

I'm using:

- CocoaPods 1.0.1
- Ruby 2.2.2
- Xcode 8.0
- OS X 10.12

By add the `--verbose` option:

```
$ pod lib lint --verbose

    MXKit (5.2.2) - Analyzing on iOS 8.0 platform.
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-App`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `MXKit` from `/Users/Meniny/MXDevelop/MXProjects/MXKit-in-Objective-C`

Resolving dependencies of 

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A MXKit

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing MXKit (5.2.2)
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `MXKit` iOS 8.0
      - Generating Info.plist file at
      `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target
      Support Files/MXKit/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at
      `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target
      Support Files/MXKit/MXKit.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at
      `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target
      Support Files/MXKit/MXKit-umbrella.h`
    - Installing target `Pods-App` iOS 8.0
      - Generating Info.plist file at
      `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target
      Support Files/Pods-App/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at
      `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target
      Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at
      `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target
      Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-umbrella.h`
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to
  `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  - Writing Lockfile in
  `../../../../../var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in
  `../../../../../private/var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `App.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

Integrating target `Pods-App` (`../../../../../var/folders/rf/gj7xyczj0t14ggvbvh9jldf80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App.xcodeproj` project)
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock' to project.
  - Running post install hooks
  Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod
  installed.
   Building with xcodebuild. 
xcodebuild clean build -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination id=DF8B8BB3-28D5-40FC-8150-7FEBD5BE12BF
2016-09-22 18:53:33.285 xcodebuild[44725:412823] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for KSImageNamed.ideplugin (com.ksuther.KSImageNamed) not present
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = -
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.0

xcodebuild: error: 'App.xcworkspace' does not exist.
 -> MXKit (5.2.2)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  xcodebuild: error: 'App.xcworkspace' does not exist.

[!] MXKit did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.

/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:75:in `block in run'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:47:in `each'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:47:in `run'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Meniny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Today I installed a new system (macOS Sierra 10.12) with Parallels Desktop 12, and:

- downloaded Xcode 8 (and installed the components)
- installed rvm 1.27.0 (latest)
- updated gem to 2.6.6
- installed CocoaPods 1.0.1

but the `pod lib lint` and `pod trunk push` commands still doesn't work.

`:(`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

When I updated cocoapods to 1.1.0.rc.2, the error has gone.
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode8.0.app/Contents/Developer/` after you install new version of Xcode